# PySimpleGui returning the input form to the original format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am trying to run a simple input to excel file. When I submit the form it wipes the button_text from my calendarbutton. My function to clear the inputs is:

```
   `def clear_input():
       for key in values:
          window[key]('')
       return None`
```

is there a way to not clear the calendarbutton text?

Comment: If using Input elements, you can have them auto-clear by setting `do_not_clear=False` in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add a conditional statement inside your function, something like the code below ( Replace 'calendar' with the actual key of your CalendarButton element )

```
def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        # Skip clearing the content of the CalendarButton
        if key != 'calendar':
            window[key]('')
    return None
```

Comment: I tried this method and the button text was still disappearing. but i was able to use this as a starting point. I added the code below.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def clear_input():
    for key, element in window.key_dict.items():
         if isinstance(element, sg.Input):
            element.update(value='')
         elif isinstance(element, sg.Combo):
            element.update(value='')
    return None
```